# Connect two k8s clusters

Tags: kubernetes, networking, devops, vpn

**Setup**

I have two clusters, one managed on digitalocean (prod) and one managed on aws (test).

DO cluster IP4 CIDR: 10.245.0.0/16

AWS cluster IP4 CIDR: 10.100.0.0/16

The one on digital ocean has cluster domain

> .svc.cluster.local

and the one on aws has cluster domain

> .svc.cluster.test

I have CoreDNS installed on both and I also have Vault installed (prod only) and consul installed (both clusters)

**Desired state**

I need to be able to connect from prod cluster to test using internal DNS (service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.(local/test) because of thanos-prometheus and vault (getting secrets on test cluster from prod vault instance)

I also need to connect to both clusters using VPN and be able to resolve http adresses in browser (preferably with wireguard)

i managed to get http adresses accesible using tailscale but cluster-to-cluster communication was still not possible

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? Thank you in advance.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can consider Rancher  https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/ as cluster management tool. join the two clusters DO and AWS k8s clusters as downstream clusters in rancher and manage them centrally using rancher

Comment: How would i reach a test cluster from the prod cluster and vice versa? Rancher doesn't do any networking and does not connect them as far as i know

Comment: you can reach the rke2 cluster using the cluster dns